# Bash : If command timeout, execute something else

Tags: bash, timeout

I am doing the following :

```
timeout 180 bash myscript.txt
```

myscript.txt is supposed to be fully executed in less than 180 seconds. IF NOT, I want emergencyscript.txt to be executed. Is it possible to do so ?

Like

```
timeout 180 [bash myscript.txt] [bash emergencyscript.txt]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exit status of `timeout` is 124 if the command times out. You can test for this explicitly.

```
timeout 180 bash myscript.txt
exit_status=$?
if [[ $exit_status -eq 124 ]]; then
    bash emergencyscript.txt
fi
```

Any other value for `exit_status` is the result of `myscript.txt` running to completion.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! timeout 180s bash myscript.txt; then bash emergencyscript.txt; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try checking to see if timeout failed or not?

```
timeout 180 bash myscript.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
#....do stuff....
fi
```

That's dependent on timeout or the script giving a non-zero exit value  if it takes too long though.

Comment: Fixed!  I like your answer more, much more specific with the checking